# Why does DecimalFormat allow characters as suffix?

Tags: java, formatting

I'm using `DecimalFormat` to parse / validate user input. Unfortunately it allows characters as a suffix while parsing.

Example code:

```
try {
  final NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat();
  System.out.println(numberFormat.parse("12abc"));
  System.out.println(numberFormat.parse("abc12"));
} catch (final ParseException e) {
  System.out.println("parse exception");
}
```

Result:

```
12
parse exception
```

I would actually expect a parse exception for both of them. How can I tell `DecimalFormat` to not allow input like `"12abc"`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the documentation of [`NumberFormat.parse`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**

Here is an example that should give you an idea how to make sure the entire string is considered.

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseCompleteString("12"));
        System.out.println(parseCompleteString("12abc"));
        System.out.println(parseCompleteString("abc12"));
    }

    public static Number parseCompleteString(String input) {
        ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
        NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        Number result = numberFormat.parse(input, pp);
        return pp.getIndex() == input.length() ? result : null;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12
null
null
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `parse(String, ParsePosition)` overload of the method, and check the .getIndex() of the ParsePosition after parsing, to see if it matches the length of the input.